# Cocos2dx v3 - Proper way to constantly save the game every certain interval?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

What would be the proper way to save the game(ex: save player's level, gained experience, current HP/MP, etc) constantly every certain interval, so that

even if the user quits the game improperly, he/she can get back to the same condition of the game?

Would this be appropriate?

```
 float _interval;

 bool GameMaster::init() {
      if(!Layer::init()) {
         return false;
      }


      // Run every frame
      _interval = 0;
      this->scheduleUpdate();
 } 

 void GameMaster::update(float dt) {
      _interval += dt;
      if(_interval > 10.0) {
           // Runs every 10 sec
           saveGame();

           // Restart the counter
           _interval = 0.0;
      }
 }
```

Comment: If it does the job it is good. I would use inbuilt scheduler to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better idea to use the Scheduler, with something like:

```
float _interval;

bool GameMaster::init() {
  if(!Layer::init()) {
     return false;
  }

  Scheduler* scheduler = Director::getInstance()->getScheduler();

  scheduler->schedule(schedule_selector(GameMaster::saveGame), this,
                      _interval, true);
} 

void GameMaster::saveGame(float deltaTime) {
    saveGame();
}
```

You can find the Scheduler's documentation [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/api-ref/cplusplus/v3x/dc/d82/classcocos2d_1_1_scheduler.html#a4a014c44c169275a007450b97215ab2f).